# What's the best way to 'normalize' a string in Redshift?

Tags: sql, string, amazon-web-services, replace, amazon-redshift

Since my texts are in Portuguese, there are many words with accent and other special characters, like: "coração", "hambúrguer", "São Paulo".

Normally, I treat these names in Python with the following function:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

def string_normalizer(text):
    result = normalize("NFKD", text.lower()).encode("ASCII", "ignore").decode("ASCII")
    return result.replace(" ", "-")
```

This would replace the blank spaces with '-', replace special characters and apply a lowercase convertion. The word "coração" would become "coracao", "São Paulo" would become "Sao Paulo" and so on. Now, I'm not sure what's the best way to do this in Redshift. My solution would be to apply multiple replaces, something like this:

```
replace(replace(replace(lower(column), 'á', 'a'), 'ç', 'c')...
```

Even though this works, it doesn't look like the best solution. Is there an easy way to normalize my string?

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, you can use the [translate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRANSLATE.html) to normalize a string. The translate function takes three arguments: the source string, the characters to replace, and the replacement characters. You can use this function to replace all the special characters in your string with their ASCII equivalent.
For example, the following query uses the translate function to replace all the special characters in a string with their ASCII equivalent. Additionally, spaces are replaced with "-" characters.

```
SELECT translate('São Paulo', ' áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ', '-aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC')
```

This query would return the string "Sao Paulo". You can use the lower function to convert the string to lowercase.
Here's an example of how you could use these functions together to normalize a string:

```
SELECT lower(translate('São Paulo', ' áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃ ÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ', '-aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC'))
```

This query would return the string "sao-paulo".